# Passing arguments to run application

Tags: c#

Looking for help on this project, I am new and might not know all terms so please bare with me.

Project contains multiple winforms panels. Start one is my dashboard then I have others that do specific functions/features. What I need to be able to do is call up the separate winforms from an outside bat file that comes from a third party software (I have no control over them).

So what I would like to do is this programname.exe runs the dashboard programname.exe -a runs a different winform with in my program. I am not sure what this is called to do this.

Any help would be great even if a place to go and look it up.

```
namespace Versi_Send_Email
{
public partial class DashBoard : Form
{
    public DashBoard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DashBoard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        INIFile inif = new INIFile(@"c:\test\mailsettings.ini");
        sitetxtbox.Text = inif.Read("Properties", "site");
        emailtotxtbox.Text = inif.Read("Properties", "personto");
        cctotxtbox.Text = inif.Read("Properties", "ccto");
        bcctextbox.Text = inif.Read("Properties", "bcto");
    }
```

Comment: Tip: your Main method gets the arguments from the command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a switch statement or a simple if-else statement. In WinForms application and in the main form loaded event, you can read the command line arguments like this

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    
foreach(string arg in args){
    if (arg=="EmployeeForm")
    {
           EmployeeForm.ShowDialog()
      else if (arg=="Department")
           Department.ShowDialog()
    }
//after all arguments are read, you can simply kill the application and main window will never appear
Application.Current.Shutdown();
return;
```

Comment: OK I am trying this but getting errors with it.  `       private void DashBoard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                if (arg == "DashBoard")
                {
                   DashBoard.ShowDialog()
                 else if (arg == "mail")
                   mail.ShowDialog()
            
                }
                
                  Application.Current.Shutdown();
                  return;
            }`